# JavaScript - How can I make it more dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, button, dynamic

JavaScript

```js
$("#answer_a_btn").click(function() {
  selectAnswer("#answer_a_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_b_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_c_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_d_btn");
});

$("#answer_b_btn").click(function() {
  deselectAnswer("#answer_a_btn");
  selectAnswer("#answer_b_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_c_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_d_btn");
});
$("#answer_c_btn").click(function() {
  deselectAnswer("#answer_a_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_b_btn");
  selectAnswer("#answer_c_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_d_btn");
});
$("#answer_d_btn").click(function() {
  deselectAnswer("#answer_a_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_b_btn");
  deselectAnswer("#answer_c_btn");
  selectAnswer("#answer_d_btn");
});
```

Because I have much more than 4 Button Answers, so how can I make it more dynamic?

```js
function selectOnlyOneExamButton(examButtonId, examButtonsIds) {
   for(var i = 0; i < examButtonsIds.length; i++)
    {
        if(examButtonsIds[i] == examButtonId)
        {
            console.log("SELECTED ANSWER " + examButtonsIds[i]);
            selectAnswer(examButtonsIds[i]);
        }
        else {
            console.log("DESELECTED ANSWER " + examButtonsIds[i]);
            deselectAnswer(examButtonsIds[i]);
        }  
    }
};
```

de-/selectAnswer() only change the color of the current de-/selected button

I don't know why this isn't working.

He printed out the same button id everytime I clicked another button or the same button...

```js
var examButtonsIds = [];
   var examButtonId = "";
   
   for(var i = 0; i < zwischenpruefungen[1].exams.length; i++)
    {
        currentExam = zwischenpruefungen[1].exams[i];
        console.log(i);
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            examscreen.appendChild(row);
        }
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.className = "col-md-6";
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id =  "exam-" + currentExam.season + "-" + currentExam.year + "-btn";
        button.className = "exam exam-btn btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block";
        examButtonId = button.getAttribute("id");
        
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("SELECT ONE EXAM BUTTON CLICKED");
            selectAnswer(this);
            $.each(".exam-btn").not(this).each(function() {
                deselectAnswer(this);
            });
        });
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = Object.keys(currentExam)[1];
        span.textContent = currentExam["season-de"] + " ";
        var span2 = document.createElement("span");
        span2.className = Object.keys(currentExam)[3];
        span2.textContent = currentExam.year;
        row.appendChild(p);
        p.appendChild(button);
        button.appendChild(span);
        button.appendChild(span2);
        examButtonsIds[i] = button.getAttribute("id");
    }
```

I do the following in my for-loop and the result is, that I get an error from jquery.min.js and the buttons keep in the clicked color if I clicked both.

[image: Mistake]
Here are the new problem. I hope you can help me?

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectAnswer(this);
    $(".answer-" + letter.toLowerCase() + "-btn").not(this).each(function() {
      deselectAnswer(this);
    });
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectAnswer(this);
    $(".answer-a-btn").not(this).each(function() {
      deselectAnswer(this);
    });
    $(".answer-b-btn").not(this).each(function() {
        deselectAnswer(this);
    });
    $(".answer-c-btn").not(this).each(function() {
        deselectAnswer(this);
    });
      $(".answer-d-btn").not(this).each(function() {
        deselectAnswer(this);
    });
    $(".answer-e-btn").not(this).each(function() {
        deselectAnswer(this);
      });
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

I thought that it would work, but it doesn't, can anyone tell me why? 
I have a complex function that works, but I want it more easy....

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectAnswer(this);
    var letterTmp = this.id.split('-')[3];
    $(".answer-" + letterTmp + "-btn").not(this).each(function() {
      deselectAnswer(this);
    });
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

I think this is the solution for me. :)

Comment: Okay, excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the buttons the same `class="answer_btn"`. Then you can do

```js
$(".answer_btn").click(function() {
  select_answer(this);
  $(".answer_btn").not(this).each(function() {
    deselect_answer(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: `button.className = "exam exam-btn btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block";`
`button.addEventListener("click", function() {`
            `console.log("SELECT ONE EXAM BUTTON CLICKED");`
            `selectAnswer(this);`
            `$.each(".exam-btn").not(this).each(function() {`
                `deselectAnswer(this);`
           ` });`
       ` });`

I do the following in my for-loop and the result is, that I get an error from jquery.min.js and the buttons keep in the clicked color if I clicked both.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit the question and add what you tried.

Comment: Okay sorry, I will do it in a minute.

Comment: Have you an idea what the problem is?

Comment: I didn't mean to use `$.each()`.

Comment: Thank you it works, but I have one question: Why gives "this" the whole button element back?

Ah, I can add "this.id" instead. Thank you for the fast help.

Comment: There's no reason to pass an ID when you can pass the element itself. Then you don't need to call `getElementById()`, you already have the element.

Comment: Okay thank you for this information. :) I'm happy now. :)

Comment: Hello Barmar,
I have another problem to this topic.
Can you help me again?

I have a website with per example 4 different questions and 4 different answers on one site. The answers are buttons how in the example before. And I have 2 for loops nested and the buttons are in the second for loop and I use your solution, but the problem is that by a click the buttons can all turned in the same color, so deselect doesn't work anymore....in this new example. Can you help me?

I added a new class to all Groupanswers...but it doesn't work.

Comment: I know the mistake, but I don't know how to fix. The for loop is going to the end of the questions per example Question E, but I don't know how to stop it so, that I can save the other letters, so that I can click the other question also right.

Comment: When you have things grouped, you generally need to use DOM navigation and selection methods relative to `$(this)`. E.g. `$(this).closest(".containerClass").find(".answer_btn")` will select all the answer buttons in the same container group.

Answer (score 0):

```
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        selectAnswer(this);
        $(".exam-btn").not(this).each(function() {
          deselectAnswer(this);
        });
        console.log(this.id);
    });
```

My Solution inspired by Barmar. :)